# Receiving an image share from another app on Android

Tags: android, delphi

/ preface /
I searched on this subject and either I'm using the wrong search terms or the answer is something so obvious I'm just being silly and about to get down-voted.
/ preface /

Using Delphi 10.2.3, how do I declare that my application can receive an image share from another application (e.g. a share from the image gallery app lists my app) and how do I get access to the image data after my app activates?

Comment: Android reference: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive. Doesn't appear to be any Delphi examples. I might come up with one later